# How to scrape IMDB id / link from JustWatch?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, imdb

Can we get the IMDB link from IMDB image of **JustWatch** website https://www.justwatch.com/in/movie/oppenheimer?

When I inspected the image elements of IMDB, there were no IMDB links.

[image: This is JustWatch Website Image]

However, when I clicked on it, it can open the **IMDB link** https://www.imdb.com/title/tt15398776/?ref_=justwatch.

[image: This is IMDB Website Image]

Is there any way of scraping the link that doesn't show up in inspect view by using python?

Thank you in advance.

**This is my code which can get only rating**

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.justwatch.com/in/movie/oppenheimer"

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
soup.select('div.jw-scoring-listing__rating span span')[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urllib` or `requests` do not work like a browser and so do not handle JavaScript or render things dynamically, but there is a way if the information is included in the static response to extract it.

You could try to check the content of script elements with `regex` for the external `imdbId`:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

match = re.search(r"\"imdbId\":\s*\"([^\"]+)\"", str(webpage))

if match:
    imdb_id_value = match.group(1)
    print(f'https://www.imdb.com/title/{imdb_id_value}/?ref_=justwatch')
else:
    print('no imdbId found')
```

That ends up in the following link if `imdbId` was found:

```
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt15398776/?ref_=justwatch
```

or in alterntive convert the content into JSON and treat it like a `dict`:

```
...
json.loads(soup.select_one('script:-soup-contains("APOLLO_STATE")').text.strip('window.__APOLLO_STATE__='))
...
```